# How can I include code inside a quotation?

Tags: support, code-formatting

This is so bloody irritating - I finally just managed to format my answer, so code appears inside a quotation using `<pre>`, and I get "*Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code*":

[image: so-error]

Ok, so how do I properly format multiline code inside a quote? Obviously this:

```
> This is my quote line

    Code Line 1
    Code Line 2
```

... does not work, because it does not render the code *inside* the quote - the result is simply this:

> This is my quote line

```
Code Line 1
Code Line 2
```

Comment: Asides from how to do that, don't ever just post "I found $article $quote the whole article" as answer.

Comment: Thanks @Magisch - I didn't quote the whole article there, just the most important code lines, which should answer the OP's question. At least, I didn't just post a link `:)`

Comment: There is *trailing* white space in the source for the example posted here. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

5 spaces are needed after `>` (1 for the quotation and 4 for the code). So:

> This class prints what is the meaning of life.
>
> ```
> class MeaningOfLife {
>  
>     private static final String MEANING_OF_LIFE = "I love Java";
>      
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         System.out.println(MEANING_OF_LIFE);
>     }
>   
> }
> ```
>
> Yes, you read right.

---

Is accomplished by:

```
> This class prints what is the meaning of life.
> 
>     class MeaningOfLife {
>     
>         private static final String MEANING_OF_LIFE = "I love Java";
>         
>         public static void main(String[] args) {
>             System.out.println(MEANING_OF_LIFE);
>         }
>     
>     }
> 
> Yes, you read right.
```

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks for the edit with the code - am accepting this as soon as the 8 minutes expire... Cheers! ALSO: note that `>` and four spaces is not enough to get this preview - you need `>` and FIVE spaces at least...

Comment: @sdbbs Yep, that's the trick. 5 spaces are needed :)

Comment: Side-note: the code formatting looks messed up a bit though. The blank lines aren't in "code" format. The same snippet on Main is fine =/.

Comment: Weird that meta and main render it differently.  I see a bug report in the future.

Comment: @sdbbs: No, it's four spaces for the code ... but there is already required a space after `>` for the quote.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The author of this answer hadn't formatting it properly. They dropped the indent back to 0 for the empty lines, rather than maintaining the code-style indent. However, having fixed it, this weird rendering persists!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I also wrote up a bug report: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321990/code-block-inside-quote-block-formatting-is-broken-on-meta

Comment: Interesting.  I tried adding ` ` (NBSP) to the end of the lines to force code formatting.  It did not work; what more, the edit history looks strange, in that it shows me editing a character in *right next to* the `>` character in some cases

Comment: http://spec.commonmark.org/0.25/#example-212

Comment: @Tunaki What to do if a code block is not desired? I mean can I preserve indented *text* in a quoting?