# Code block inside quote block formatting is broken on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, code-formatting, formatting

After seeing *[How to include code inside a quotation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321978/how-to-include-code-inside-a-quotation)* and its [associated answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321979/4342498), I saw that a code block inside a quote block formatting is broken on meta. If we use the example from the answer on meta we get:

> This class prints what is the meaning of life.
>
> ```
> class MeaningOfLife {
>
>     private static final String MEANING_OF_LIFE = "I love Java";
>
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         System.out.println(MEANING_OF_LIFE);
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> Yes, you read right.

But on main we get:

[image]

As you can see on meta the code is rendered as multiple single lines of code, but on main it is rendered as one single code block.

<sup>The views and opinions expressed in the code block is that of the original author and do not reflect the views and opinions of this C++ programmer.</sup>

This is how the two blocks are rendered on my system (Windows 7 Pro Chrome Version 50.0.2661.87 m):

[image]

Comment: As long as the java is referring to coffee this non-java non-C++ programmer is in full agreement. Speaking about which... *brb*

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. I see a single <pre> element in your meta blockquote. The only thing that's different is the lack of syntax highlighting.

Comment: @BoltClock The top and and bottom code blocks look the same to you?

Comment: @NathanOliver: They do. On Firefox, if that helps.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I was just messing with user styles yesterday after that whole prettify hoopla. Yeah I remember the darker background now.

Comment: @BoltClock Okay.  I added a screen cap of how it looks on my screen just in case others have the same thing.

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 49 as well.

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Mac and I saw the same thing.

Comment: *Java* Eeew... *C++ programmer* EEEW!  GROSS!

Comment: That is really weird. It looks like plain, fixed-width text highlighted with gray.

Comment: Reproduced with FF 45 on Linux.

Comment: I fixed a few oddities with the poster's Markdown (use of HTML, dropping indent back to 0 for "empty" lines inside the quote), but the problem persists. Bah! It's being rendered with the inline-code (i.e. backticks) formatting rather than code block formatting. Probably a renderer bug.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If it makes you feel any better I used the exact same block of text on meta and main.  main required not changes at all.  It just worked.

Comment: A dev casually lobbed in a huge sweeping change to the syntax highlighting system this week without any consultation or testing so that's probably why

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox 46 for Windows.

Comment: @rene Q/A? You mean QC...

Comment: Repro'd FF 46.0 Windows 10

Comment: Wait, did you make a screen shot of a screen shot?

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox Developer Edition 48.0a2 with e10s on Windows 10

Comment: *The views _and_ opinions expressed in the code block is that of the original author and do not reflect the views and opinions of this C++ programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the winner is... @NathanOliver.

What was happening is that in meta blockquotes have the same background color as code blocks usually have. Thus, a custom darker color is set for code blocks inside blockquotes via css. Code blocks are positioned as *inline*, hence the strange look.

Solution: code blocks inside blockquotes are now *inline-block* and that's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

The CSS contains several instances of `\9` (escape code for <kbd>TAB</kbd> character) causing things to break.

A bug report has been made here: [Bad CSS on quoted code on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322072/bad-css-in-meta)

Comment: I just added `max-height: 600px;
    display: block;` to the element through the inspector and it did render to code block correctly

Comment: Editing the offending CSS rule to remove the `\9` fixes it too ;)

Comment: For whatever reason chrome was not letting me do that so I just added the corrected code.  It is my first time doing that so most likely I am missing something.

Comment: That's weird because there isn't any tab character in the [original code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321979/1743880), just spaces. And it doesn't seem to work in Firefox?

Comment: @NathanOliver Whoa! The spaces in your comment made it overflow the code highlight.