# Bad CSS on quoted code on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta, code

As seen in [How to include code inside a quotation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321978/how-to-include-code-inside-a-quotation)

A very quick investigation (literally, right-click, Inspect Element :D) found the cause. For some reason, the minifier has interpreted tabs to be part of the CSS property value, resulting in `display:block\9` (`\9` being tab in CSS escape code) which, obviously breaks things completely.

Bad minifier!

Comment: I also found a `max-height:600px\9;` which gets declared as invalid by Firefox.

Comment: Would you mind posting this as an answer on my bug report: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321990/code-block-inside-quote-block-formatting-is-broken-on-meta?

Comment: Huh, I don't see that with the latest Firefox. And there is no tab character in the answer I think.

Comment: For reference this is usually an IE CSS hack ([CSS \9 in width property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004765/css-9-in-width-property)), but I have no idea what the purpose would be here.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara "This simply means that the one specific line of CSS ending with a \9; in place of the ; is only valid in IE 7, 8, & 9." if it was intentional, they didn't expect other browsers to try and parse the rule.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, I was just questioning what the significance of this particular instance of the CSS property hack is, but I don't feel like firing up my IE VM's to test it out in.

Comment: I'm not so sure this is the bug. It seems more like a workaround not being applied, and the real bug is that a colour is applied to `code` elements inside `blockquote`, but the same colour is not applied not to `pre` elements in side `blockquote`.

Comment: Fixed: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/331612/4574